# checkinstall --include option not working

Tags: debian, systemd, package-management, checkinstall

I am successfully able to create a .deb package from source using `checkinstall`. However can someone help me with why I cannot add custom/additional files to the package created using the `--include` option with `checkinstall`.

For instance I use `checkinstall –-install=no --include="/home/user/*package-name*/include-list.txt"` , I assume this should be sufficient to include additional files & dirs listed in the `include-list.txt` in the package(.deb) created.

My `include-list.txt` is just a simple txt file and contains 1 line as follows :
`/etc/systemd/system/example.service` & my intention is to include this .service file as a part of the package created.

I have checked the checkinstall help and its seems like `--include` option is the way to go.

Any help will be appreciated.